# read and find string from text file

Tags: java, java-io

I am loading text file contents to GUI using this code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("text.txt"));
    String line;                
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("TITLE")) {
            jTextField2.setText(line.substring(11, 59));
        }            
    }
    in.close();        
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Then contents of text.txt file:

```
JOURNAL   journal name                                               A12340001
TITLE     Sound, mobility and landscapes of exhibition: radio-guided A12340002
          tours at the Science Museum                                A12340003
AUTHOR    authors name                                               A12340004
```

On `jTextField2` I am getting this line: *"Sound, mobility and landscapes of exhibition: radio-guided"*. 
The problem is I don't know how to get to `jTextField2` the string of next line *"tours at the Science Museum"*.

I would like to ask how can I get both line on `jTextField2` i.e. *"Sound, mobility and landscapes of exhibition: radio-guided tours at the Science Museum"*?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with either Swing or I/O, but parsing data .. Start with a hard-coded `String` (in the code) and parse it into objects representing each entry (not line) in a command line app.

Comment: Is there a fixed amount of lines in the file?

Comment: @Ni. unfortunately no

Comment: is your file tab separated?

Comment: Will this line be always after the title line?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela file contents separated by column, so in file I should read text until column 59, these A12340001, ... I don't need to read

Comment: @Ni. yes, every Keywords (i.e. Title, Author, ...) have following text from substring 11 to 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 and assuming that the columns have a fixed number of characters, you could something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> sections = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> content = (List<String>)Files.lines(Paths.get("files/input.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    String lastKey = "";
    for(String s : content){
        String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim(); 
        String v = s.substring(10, s.length()-9).trim();
        if(k.equals(""))
            k=lastKey;
        sections.merge(k, v, String::concat);
        lastKey=k;
    }
    System.out.println(sections.get("TITLE"));
}
```

The first column is the key. When the keys does not exist, the last key is used. A `Map` is used to store the keys and the values. When the key already exist, the value is merged with the existing one by concatenation.

This code outputs the expected String: `Sound, mobility and landscapes of exhibition: radio-guidedtours at the Science Museum`.

**EDIT:** For Java 7

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Map<String, String> sections = new HashMap<>();
    String s = "", lastKey="";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/input.txt"))) {
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim();
            String v = s.substring(10, s.length() - 9).trim();
            if (k.equals(""))
                k = lastKey;
            if(sections.containsKey(k))
                v = sections.get(k) + v; 
            sections.put(k,v);
            lastKey = k;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("The file could not be found or read");
    }

    System.out.println(sections.get("TITLE"));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I should use Java 7, @joel314 is there same way for Java 7?

Comment: Here you go. Same idea, the code is just not as clean as in Java 8. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked and I also accept your answer. +1

Comment: I apologize for the frequent change of my choice which answer is acceptable or suitable, to decide it little a bit took a time for me, I tried to extend the code for my purpose and the code of @joel314 was flexible than the code of Ian2thedv.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a `MyFile` class that does the parsing for you, storing key-value-pairs in a `Map<String, String>`, which you can then access. This will make your code more readable and will be easier to maintain.

Something like the following:

```
public class MyFile {
    private Map<String, String> map;
    private String fileName;

    public MyFile(String fileName)  {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void parse() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = br.readLine();
        String key = "";
        while (line != null) {
            //Only update key if the line starts with non-whitespace
            key = line.startsWith(" ") ? title : line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")).trim();
            //If the key is contained in the map, append to the value, otherwise insert a new value
            map.put(key, map.get(key) == null ? line.substring(line.indexOf(" "), 59).trim() : map.get(key) + line.substring(line.indexOf(" "), 59).trim());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }

    public String getEntry(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry entry:map.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey()).append(" : ").append(entry.getValue()).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This will parse the entire file first. The expected format of the file is:

```
0 ... 59
[KEY][WHITE SPACE][VALUE]
0 ... 59
[WHITE SPACE][VALUE TO APPEND TO PREVIOUS KEY]
```

This allows for variable length keys.

Allowing you to handle exceptions separately, and then easily reference the contents of the file like so:

```
MyFile journalFile = new MyFile("text.txt");
try {
    journalFile.parse();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Malformed file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

jTextField2.setText(journalFile.getEntry("TITLE"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your code work perfect!! +1

Comment: I w'd like to ask if in case of TITLE `substring(11, 59)` and AUTHOR case `substring(11, 18)`, can I write something like TITLE->`journalFile.parse();` and AUTHOR-> `journalFile.parse2();`?

Comment: @hub why do you want to do that? Do you only want the partial entries in some cases?

Comment: I have about 20 keywords such as TITLE, AUTHOR, AFFILIATION,... and every keyword should be read with different `substring`, I was thinking I can implement your code for other keywords with different `substring`, but I couldn't.

Comment: @hub I updated the answer a bit. It now allows for variable length keys and values. Note: it is expected that key and value pairs are limited to 59 characters and separated by `" "`. If a value is part of the previous key, the line should also start with `" "`

Answer (score 0):

An empty (all spaces) first column indicates that a line is the continuation of the previous one. So you can buffer the lines and repeatedly concatenate them, until you get a non-empty first column, and then write/print the whole line.

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt")) ;
        String line ;
        String fullTitle = "" ;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //extract the fields from the line
            String heading = line.substring(0, 9) ;
            String titleLine = line.substring(10, 69) ;

            //does not select on "TITLE", prints all alines
            if(heading.equals("         ")) {
                fullTitle = fullTitle + titleLine ;
            } else {
                System.out.println(fullTitle) ;
                fullTitle = titleLine ;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(fullTitle) ; //flush the last buffered line

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e) ;
    }
```

Comment: it can work if `Author` also have 3 or 5 line of Authors name? Because in text file can be several empty spaces in substring(0, 9).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this
First of all read the entire file into a string object.
then get the indexes of the TITLE and AUTHOR 
like `int start=str.indexOf("TITLE"); and int end=str.indexOf("AUTHOR");`
then add the length of TITLE into start index `start+="TITLE".length();`
and subtract the length of AUTHOR from end index `end-="AUTHOR".length();`
at last you have the start and end index of text that you want.
so get the text like.

```
String title=str.subString(start,end);
```