# get count number of HashMap value

Tags: java, java-io

Using the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129625/read-and-find-string-from-text-file) loading text file contents to GUI:

```
Map<String, String> sections = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> sections2 = new HashMap<>();
String s = "", lastKey="";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim();
        String v = s.substring(10, s.length() - 50).trim();
        if (k.equals(""))
            k = lastKey;
        if(sections.containsKey(k))
            v = sections.get(k) + v; 
        sections.put(k,v);
        lastKey = k;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
System.out.println(sections.get("AUTHOR"));
System.out.println(sections2.get("TITLE"));
```

In case of if contents of input.txt:

```
AUTHOR    authors name
          authors name
          authors name
          authors name
TITLE     Sound, mobility and landscapes of exhibition: radio-guided
          tours at the Science Museum
```

Now I want to count the values in HashMap, but `sections.size()` counting all data line stored in text file.

I w'd like to ask how can I count the items, i.e. values `v` in `sections`? How can I get number *4*, according to *authors name*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the AUTHOR has a 1 to many relationship, you should map it to a `List` structure instead of a `String`.

For example:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sections = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> sections2 = new HashMap<>();
String s = "", lastKey="";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim();
        String v = s.substring(10, s.length() - 50).trim();
        if (k.equals(""))
            k = lastKey;

        ArrayList<String> authors = null;
        if(sections.containsKey(k))
        {
            authors = sections.get(k);
        }
        else
        {
            authors = new ArrayList<String>();
            sections.put(k, authors);
        }
        authors.add(v);
        lastKey = k;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}

// to get the number of authors
int numOfAuthors = sections.get("AUTHOR").size();

// convert the list to a string to load it in a GUI
String authors = "";
for (String a : sections.get("AUTHOR"))
{
    authors += a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now count is working, but I can't `setText` to `jTextField1` `jTextField1.setText(sections.get("AUTHOR"));` ?

Comment: If you want to convert the list to a string, then just loop through the list and concatenate the string as you wish. I will show an example in my post.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: I w'd like to ask one question related to `numOfAuthors`, I want to use it for `jButton1.doClick(numOfAuthors);`, but it doesn't work properly, I can't understand why.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do there since the doClick() method does not take any parameters. I would post this as another question with the relevant code along with the error you are getting.