# jButton HashMap count click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Using the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291618/get-count-number-of-hashmap-value) loading text file contents to GUI:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sections = new HashMap<>();
String s = "", lastKey="";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim();
        String v = s.substring(10, s.length() - 50).trim();
        if (k.equals(""))
            k = lastKey;

        ArrayList<String> authors = null;
        if(sections.containsKey(k))
        {
            authors = sections.get(k);
        }
        else
        {
            authors = new ArrayList<String>();
            sections.put(k, authors);
        }
        authors.add(v);
        lastKey = k;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

With the help of @Michael Markidis counting the `HashMap` items using this code:

```
// to get the number of authors
int numOfAuthors = sections.get("AUTHOR").size();
```

Now I w'd like to use `numOfAuthors` as a parameter of `jButton1`, for example:

```
jButton1.doClick(numOfAuthors);
```

Actually general structure of GUI: I have `jPanel1` with `jTextField1` and `jButton1`. `jButton1` adding dynamic `tf` to `jPanel2`.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SubPanel sub = new SubPanel();
    jPanel2.add(sub);
    jPanel2.revalidate();  
}
```

The number of items in `HashMap` is *`12`*, so I wo'd like to use this number as a parameter of `jButton1` and click *`12`* times and add additional *`12`* `sub`'s.

```
    System.out.println(numOfAuthors);
    Output: 12
```

But for this moment `jButton1` adds just *`1`* `sub`.

I can't understand why it doesn't work properly.

Comment: What is the layout manager of `jPanel2` ?

Comment: @Berger VerticalLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a class which implements `ActionListener`

```
public class Clicker implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Add a constructor to this class which takes a number

```
public class Clicker implements ActionListener {

    private int count;

    public Clicker(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Use this to make determinations about what you need to do, for example

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        SubPanel sub = new SubPanel();
        jPanel2.add(sub);
    }
}
```

You would then register this `ActionListener` against your `JButton`

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new Clicker(12));
```

Remember, if you've previously added any `ActionListener`s to the button, you'll want to remove them first

Have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

For a slightly more advanced approach, you might consider having a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: Ohh Sorry I was misunderstood. Thank you for your effort, your method work perfect!! Accepted answer and +1.