# assign HashMap values to dynamic jComboBoxes

Tags: java, swing

I am loading text file contents to GUI and counting `HashMap` values using this code:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sections = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> sections2 = new HashMap<>();
String s = "", lastKey="";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim();
        String v = s.substring(10, s.length() - 50).trim();
        if (k.equals(""))
            k = lastKey;

            ArrayList<String> authors = null;
        if(sections.containsKey(k))
        {
            authors = sections.get(k);
        }
        else
        {
            authors = new ArrayList<String>();
            sections.put(k, authors);
        }
        authors.add(v);
        lastKey = k;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}

// to get the number of authors
int numOfAuthors = sections.get("AUTHOR").size();
// to count HashMap value
jButton1.addActionListener(new Clicker(numOfAuthors));
jButton1.doClick();

// convert the list to a string to load it in a GUI
String authors = "";
for (String a : sections.get("AUTHOR"))
{
    authors += a;
}
   jcb1.setSelectedItem(authors);
```

The `ActionListener` of `jButton1` was borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317634/jbutton-hashmap-count-click).

Now I want to assign `AUTHOR` (the number of items in `HashMap` is *12*, so `jButton1` will add dynamic *12* `jComboBoxes`) values to dynamically created `jComboBoxes`.

I have tried this code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("input.txt"));
String str=null;
int i = 0;
while( (str = br.readLine()) !=null ) {
    String v = str.substring(12, str.length() - 61).trim();

    if(i == 0) {              
        jcb1.setSelectedItem(v);

    } else {
        SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) jPanel2.getComponent(i - 1);
        JComboBox jcb = panel.getJcb();
        jcb.setSelectedItem(v);
    }

    i++;
}
```

But this code read from *input.txt* all lines (*70 lines*), but I want to assign just that *12* values from `AUTHOR` field and show them on `jcb`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Sorry, but *what* are you trying to do again? Please clarify, please post your [mcve] or as much of an mcve as possible.

Comment: I'm still very unclear as to your problem, your code, and your question, but hopefully Michael's answer is what you need. It seems he has helped you previously and so understands your set up better than most. Still if you could put more effort into the question, it will be better for future visitors. Also a side note: **never** have this code: `catch (IOException e) { }`. This isn't just bad code, it is downright **dangerous** code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to re-read the entire text file again in order to complete the setup of the GUI. I would just read the text file once, then use the `Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sections = new HashMap<>();` object to complete the setup of the GUI.

This could be the process for you:

1) Read the entire file and return the sections HashMap.

2) Setup the `jPanel2` by adding the `SubPanels` to it (e.g. based on the number of Authors).

3) Setup the `JComboBox's` by adding the data stored in the `HashMap` (e.g. the mapped `ArrayList's`).

For number 1), I would just create a method that reads the file and returns the `HashMap`.

### Read The File

**Example** (Adapted from your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291618/get-count-number-of-hashmap-value)):

```
public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> getSections ()
{
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sections = new HashMap<>();
    String s = "", lastKey = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")))
    {
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String k = s.substring(0, 10).trim();
            String v = s.substring(10, s.length() - 50).trim();
            if (k.equals(""))
                k = lastKey;

            ArrayList<String> authors = null;
            if (sections.containsKey(k))
            {
                authors = sections.get(k);
            }
            else
            {
                authors = new ArrayList<String>();
                sections.put(k, authors);
            }

            // don't add empty strings
            if (v.length() > 0)
            {
                authors.add(v);
            }
            lastKey = k;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sections;
}
```

### GUI Setup

**Note**: This code can be put wherever you are setting up the GUI now, I'm just placing all in the method below for an example.

```
public void setupGUI ()
{
    // read the file and get the map
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sections = getSections();

    // get the authors
    ArrayList<String> authors = sections.get("AUTHOR");

    // Setup the jPanel2 by adding the SubPanels
    int num = authors.size();
    jButton1.addActionListener(new Clicker(num));
    jButton1.doClick();

    // Setup the JComboBox's by adding the data stored in the map
    for (int i = 0; i < authors.size(); i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        // not sure if getComponent() is zero or 1-baed so adjust the index accordingly.
        SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) jPanel2.getComponent(index);

        // Not sure if you already have the JComboBox in the SubPanel
        // If not, you can add them here.

        JComboBox jcb = panel.getJcb();
        jcb.setSelectedItem(authors.get(i));
    }
}
```

**Side Note**: I'm not sure why you are creating 12 separate SubPanel's, each with its own JComboBox? Maybe you want to consider how you can better layout the GUI. Just a consideration. In either case, you can use the above examples are a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I w'd like to ask in case of `for (int i = 1; i < institute.size(); i++) { int index = i;            
            SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) jPanel2.getComponent(index-1);           
            jcb1.setSelectedItem(institute.get(0));
            JComboBox jcb = panel.getJcb();            
            jcb.setSelectedItem(institute.get(i));`  I am getting all _13_ `HashMap` values in dynamic `jComboBoxes`, but in the end it adds additional _14th_ empty `jComboBox`. Something am I doing wrong? P.S. About GUI layout: Thank you I will try to consider better way.

Comment: What is the size of institute list?

Comment: Institute size is 13

Comment: It must be somewhere else in your code. That for loop is not adding any jComboBox's. It is just setting selected items in them. Look at the code where you create them and see how many you actually create and why.

Comment: I found that `ArrayList authors` contain blank line, that is why adding empty `jcb`, I w'd like to ask how can I remove empty line in `authors` field?

Comment: I updated my answer. See the comment "// don't add empty strings" Instead of removing it, it won't add it in the first place. That should work.

Comment: You are the B.E.S.T (Breathtaking_Excellent_Supreme_ Thoughtful) programmer I have ever met. :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I accept your answer and +1.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you saying those things. I'm glad I was able to help.