# if/else statement based on comma count

Tags: java, if-statement

I am loading text file contents to GUI using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375450/assign-hashmap-values-to-dynamic-jcomboboxes).
I use `String.split()` method to split the line.
Now by counting commas in some line I want to set them to `jComboBoxes` and `jTextFields`. I tried to use `if/else statement` to switch condition for `jComboBoxes` and `jTextFields` in below code.
But when I used `if/else` for 2 cases, that is `commas<4` and `commas<3`, I found that `jComboBoxes` and `jTextFields` are interfere each other. 
In case of when `commas==3`, `jTextField1` getting the value of `t1[1]` *except* `t1[2]`.

I would like to ask how can I write `if/else` for this case without interfering each other (`jComboBoxes` and `jTextFields`)?

```
    String[] t1 = authors.toString().split(",");

      int commas = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < authors.toString().length(); i++) {
     if(authors.toString().charAt(i) == ',') commas++;

   if(commas<4){
     jcb1.setSelectedItem(t1[0]);

     jTextField1.setText(t1[1]);

     jTextField2.setText(t1[4]);
 }
   else if(commas<3){
     jcb1.setSelectedItem(t1[0]);

     jTextField1.setText(t1[2]);

     jTextField2.setText(t1[3]);        
 }                  
 }
      System.out.println(commas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the logic here,

if comma count us equals to say `1` then the first `if` will be entered and the second `else if` would not.

Try swapping the order around or use a switch statement.

Also you are going to get an out of bounds exception because arrays are zero based.

```
 4 commas will be in tl[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I used switch statement, this solved my problem.